# How Allah Decides

Tags: allah, blessings-of-allah

As I've heard everything happens according to the Allah's consent.

So imagine there's a cricket match between Pakistan and Afghanistan. Both the team members are worshiping Allah before the game and while playing the game. So in that case how Allah decide who should win the game. And if Pakistan wins then what's the point of worshiping Allah by Afghanistan players? (And other eay round)

Comment: Do you think skill means nothing to Allah? Also, worshiping is not done to get something. Worshiping is done to be thankful. Perhaps you meant "dua." And dua is not guaranteed to be returned in this world.

Comment: So if skill is the key then why worship matters before a game?

Comment: I don't know. I've never done it. I would say it is very strange to worship for winning a sports game. Also keep in mind that skill is not the only reason people win games. The other reason is just chance. And Allah chooses chance.

Comment: @TheZ so in that case, skill may override Allah's decision which he chose through `chances`

Comment: @Explorer Allah gives every person opportunity to decide, wheter to believe or not, wheter to improve their skills or not. And the mechanism of this world proves that someone that has better skills will have more chances to win. And the creator of that mechanism is Allah.

Comment: Skill makes the chances. For example, the skill of one team relative to the other could cause the chances to be 80/20. But, ultimately Allah chooses, so there is a possibility Allah can choose to answer one team's prayer by choosing to let them win. But, again, I don't know. It is also possible that Allah ignores sport game duas, because they are highly frivolous. Allah knows best.

Comment: I'd recommend you also look into the Luh e Mahfuz ... it is the Preserved Tablet that contains details of everything. It is said to have been created before the creation of the universe. Quran is a subset of it as per some scholars.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Allah is not human-being to need time to think to decide ...

Secondly, Dua is regularly effective, and it might be corresponding its amount and other conditions...

Thirdly, the world is not a place that every thing happen miracle but also by its natural conditions ...

Comment: Well, who decides on these natural conditions though? Isn't it Allah?

Comment: @SpiderRico: The natural laws are *fixed* and *upheld* by Allah.

Answer (score 0):

Worship is not done for skill in a cricket game. Both teams can worship and they will be rewarded or punished for their actions. However, worshipping or duas do not guarantee what you request I mean imagine worshipping or making dua for the utmost happiness, money or whatever and getting it just like that. You can be rewarded for your dua and worship in the afterlife and sometimes your dua may be accepted and you may get what you want in this life but that is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

**MY VIEW**

Dua (Pray) is like request. It depends on **Allah** to accept it or not. And there is a fix time for the acceptance of every pray (Dua). Well to think in that way that How Allah decides is not under our capabilities. Even if we try we can't. And one more our non accepted prayers will be added in our good deeds at the **Day Of Result**

Answer (score 0):

Everything happens according to Allah's will. When I make dua I asks Allah to do something according to my wish, however Allah is free to accept this dua or to ignore it. As a Muslim I will be satisfied with whatever Allah does. The point of making Dua is firstly to express my devotion and reliance to Allah and secondly because I will make effort even if there is a chance that it may not bear fruit.

I also do this in everyday life, I take medicine when I get sick, although I know that there is a chance that it may not cure me. I attend to my shop waiting for customers, even though I know that there is a chance that no one will buy from me. When I leave I lock my door to stop thieves, even though I know that there is a chance that a someone will break in anyways.

Answer (score 0):

> I've heard that everything is done with Allah's consent.

This is al-Ghazali's *occasionalism*, he pointed that even a flame on a candle wouldn't burn without Allah's intervention.

> So how should Allah decide who should win the game?

Allah endowed men and women with free will and the choice to choose between good and evil as well as many other things.  It isn't Allah that 'decides' who wins the game of cricket but men who 'decide' through their Allah granted free will.

Comment: Good explanation for blind fools

Comment: @explorer: Al-Ghazali was no fool nor blind.